# tcl foreach line split on spaces2

Tags: tcl

how can I prevent the line from being separated with a blank at foreach?

Variable "start" is "OK done" and output is in first line Ok and second line done

if i start directly in bash htkrd it comes back here

```
test@home:~$ htkrd
text1 aa
text2 bb 
text3 cc
text4 dd
text5 ee
text6 ff
OK done
test@home:~$
```

script:

```
proc pub:test {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set start [exec bash -c "htkrd"]
    #foreach i $start {
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$start"
    #}
}
```

wrong output:

```
[28.06.20/10:11:12] <@testbot> text1 aa
```

correct output:

```
 <@testbot> text1
 <@testbot> text2
 <@testbot> text3
 <@testbot> text4
 <@testbot> text5
 <@testbot> text6
 <@testbot> OK done
```

Comment: Don't use `foreach`? `putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$start"` or whatever.

Comment: hello, i took the foreach out and now he only writes the first line

Comment: Your orginal question had nothing to indicate that you had more than a single line to deal with. So... `foreach` and `split` on newline.

Comment: thanks, with foreach and split working

Answer (score 0):

To split the output of a subprocess by newlines, use `split … "\n"`. You can then iterate over each of the lines with `foreach` and decide what to do with it (print it or not). Here's how to skip all visually-empty lines, which is probably a very good idea as a first attempt at producing output for IRC.

```
proc pub:test {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set start [exec bash -c "htkrd"]
    foreach line [split $start "\n"] {
        set trimmed [string trim $line]; # Remove extra whitespace
        if {$trimmed ne ""} {;           # If not empty after trimming
            putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$trimmed"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, more complex manipulations of the lines are possible, but you'll need to be very clear about what you want to happen for them for us to be able to help. (The issue is that there's several ways to get the words out of a line and *the details matter very much when doing this.* Tcl has many tools for string manipulation.)

Note that I'd most likely split the code at about this point so that the code for deciding how to transform a single line is separate from the rest. Like that, you can just think about that part of the problem rather than having everything mulched together at once

```
proc TransformLine {line} {
    # Trivial example; remove whitespace and last two letter word if present
    set trimmed [string trim $line]
    return [regsub {\s+\w{2}$} $trimmed ""]
}

proc pub:test {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set start [exec bash -c "htkrd"]
    foreach line [split $start "\n"] {
        set processed [TransformLine $line]
        if {$processed ne ""} {
            putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$processed"
        }
    }
}
```

You *might* be able to write that transformer procedure like this:

```
proc TransformLine {line} {
    # Depends on the lines being well-formed Tcl lists; most input mostly is…
    if {[string length [lindex $line end]] == 2} {
        set line [lrange $line 0 end-1]
    }
    return [join $line]
}
```